# Can't get resources on Maven JavaFX project

Tags: image, maven, url, javafx, fonts

In a simple JavaFX project using Maven, I am trying to load an image located in `src/main/resources/images/logo.png` and a font located in `src/main/resources/fonts/pikzel.ttf` from my app located in `src/main/java/com/example/App.java`. I am using Intellij Idea.

From my understanding I should use the URLs starting from the resources folder, but both attempts of loading the image and the font crash the app upon start. Is there such a way to load resources easily from a relative URL ?

```java
Image logo = new Image("/images/logo.png");
ImageView logoView = new ImageView(logo);
logoView.setPreserveRatio(true);
logoView.setFitHeight(100);

Label titleLabel = new Label("Regirocko");
Font pikzel = Font.loadFont("/fonts/pikzel.ttf", 36);
titleLabel.setFont(pikzel);
```

## Update

My project is modular. Its structure currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5CGm.png). I managed to fix the image by adding this to `module-info.java` :

```java
opens atzelord.regirocko.images;
```

and using this in MenuView to load the image :

```java
Image logo = new Image("atzelord/regirocko/images/logo.png");
```

However, adding a similar line for the fonts folder in `module-info.java` and doing the same doesn't seem to work for the font and throws an exception :

```java
Font pikzel = Font.loadFont("atzelord/regirocko/fonts/pikzel.ttf", 36);
```

```
C:\Users\Joan\.jdks\openjdk-19.0.1\bin\java.exe -javaagent:C:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\231.8109.175\lib\idea_rt.jar=51977:C:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\231.8109.175\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\19\javafx-controls-19.jar;C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\19\javafx-graphics-19.jar;C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\19\javafx-base-19.jar;C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\19\javafx-fxml-19.jar;C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\19\javafx-fxml-19-win.jar -p "C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\19\javafx-base-19-win.jar;C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\19\javafx-controls-19-win.jar;C:\Users\Joan\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\19\javafx-graphics-19-win.jar;C:\Users\Joan\Documents\Mes documents\Java\regirocko\target\classes" -m atzelord.regirocko/atzelord.regirocko.App
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.text.Font.getNativeFont()" because "<parameter1>" is null
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.text.Font$1.getNativeFont(Font.java:68)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.text.FontHelper.getNativeFont(FontHelper.java:46)
    at javafx.controls@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils.computeTextHeight(Utils.java:138)
    at javafx.controls@19/javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.computeMinLabeledPartHeight(LabeledSkinBase.java:841)
    at javafx.controls@19/javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.computeMinHeight(LabeledSkinBase.java:311)
    at javafx.controls@19/javafx.scene.control.Control.computeMinHeight(Control.java:499)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:1062)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1571)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1981)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.getMaxAreaHeight(Region.java:2262)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeMaxMinAreaHeight(Region.java:2131)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.HBox.computeMinHeight(HBox.java:422)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:1062)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1571)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1981)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getAreaHeights(VBox.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeContentHeight(VBox.java:529)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeMinHeight(VBox.java:407)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:1062)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1571)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:2046)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getAreaHeights(VBox.java:451)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.layout.VBox.layoutChildren(VBox.java:562)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1207)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:592)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1786)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1163)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1239)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1254)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:277)
    at atzelord.regirocko/atzelord.regirocko.App.start(App.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application atzelord.regirocko.App

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is your code modular (i.e., do you have a `module-info.java` file)?

Comment: Yes, there is this file. I used the Intellij JavaFX project template

Comment: See if adding `opens images;` and `opens fonts;` directives to your module-info file makes your code work. Or you can just use the approach shown in [Sai Dandem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77269316/6395627).

Comment: *”crash the app upon start”* -> an actual crash would be unusual.  Normally there would be an exception and stack trace.  If there is one, then you should provide the full stack trace in the question as text formatted as code.

Comment: *”Is there such a way to load resources easily from a relative URL ?”* -> the path you are providing `/images/logo.png` is absolute not relative.  Check your build output directory or jar contents.  Ensure that the image is under the location `{projectdir}/target/classes/images/logo.png` (it should be based on your problem description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For a more comprehensive Q&A on resource loading in JavaFX and helpful debugging techniques, see [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/6395627).*

---

## Image Resource

The [`Image(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) constructor accepts four "types" of string arguments. This is documented by the [class documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

> If a URL string is passed to a constructor, it *[may]* be any of the following:
>
> 1. **the name of a resource that can be resolved by the context `ClassLoader` for this thread** *[emphasis added]*
> 2. a file path that can be resolved by `File`
> 3. a URL that can be resolved by `URL` and for which a protocol handler exists
>
> The RFC 2397 "data" scheme for URLs is supported in addition to the protocol handlers that are registered for the application. If a URL uses the "data" scheme, the data must be base64-encoded and the MIME type must be a subtype of the `image` type. The MIME type must match the image format of the data contained in the URL. In case of a mismatch between MIME type and image format, the image will be loaded if the image format can be determined by JavaFX, and a warning will be logged.

You are trying to pass a resource name, so the relevant part has been emphasized. Note it says it uses the [context class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader()) to find the resource. That ultimately means the [`ClassLoader#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) method is being used. But note the following part of that method's documentation:

> Resources in named modules are subject to the encapsulation rules specified by `Module.getResourceAsStream`. Additionally, and except for the special case where the resource has a name ending with `".class"`, **this method will only find resources in packages of named modules when the package is opened unconditionally** *[emphsis added]* (even if the caller of this method is in the same module as the resource).

Since your code is modular and your image is in a package within your module, the image resource is [encapsulated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). So, if you want to pass a plain resource name string to `Image`, then all this means the following:

1. The resource name must be absolute. But note typically it should not start with a leading forward slash, as the `ClassLoader` version of `getResource` does not work with leading `/`. However, the implementation of `Image` will strip the leading `/` if it's present (this is an *implementation detail*).
2. You must add an `opens <image-package>;` directive to your `module-info.java` file.

The other option is to use [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)). Using it means:

1. The resource name can be absolute (*with* a leading `/`) or relative to the class's location (i.e., package). Note for relative resource names, neither `..` nor `.` are supported.
2. The image's package only has to be `opens` to the module calling `getResource(String)`. If the resource is in the same module as the caller module, then you don't have to add any `opens` directives to your `module-info.java` file.
3. Though, if I'm not mistaken, the resource has to be inside the module of the class you're calling `getResource(String)` on. Please correct me if I'm mistaken here.

This would look something like:

```java
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/foo.png").toString());
```

Assuming the image resource is at `src/main/resources/images/foo.png` in a typical Maven or Gradle setup.

---

## Font Resource

The [`Font#loadFont(String,double)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#loadFont(java.lang.String,double)) method does not accept resource names.

> Loads a font resource from the specified URL. If the load is successful such that the location is readable, and it represents a supported font format then a `Font` object will be returned.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Any failure such as a malformed URL being unable to locate or read from the resource, or if it doesn't represent a font, will result in a `null` return. It is the application's responsibility to check this before use.

It only accepts URLs. Given your font is a resource, you have to use a method such as [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)). Something like:

```java
Font font = Font.loadFonts(getClass().getResource("/fonts/bar.ttf").toString(), 36);
```

Assuming the font file is at `src/main/resources/fonts/bar.ttf` in a typical Maven or Gradle setup.

Also, note you should make sure to only *load* the font once:

> On a successful (non-null) return the font will be registered with the FX graphics system for creation by available constructors and factory methods, and the application should use it in this manner rather than calling this method again, which would repeat the overhead of downloading and installing the font.

Answer (score 4):

As there is not much details of your project structure, I suggest you to try the below approach of loading resources from class.

```
Image logo = new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png").toExternalForm());
ImageView logoView = new ImageView(logo);
logoView.setPreserveRatio(true);
logoView.setFitHeight(100);

Label titleLabel = new Label("Regirocko");
Font pikzel = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResource("/fonts/pikzel.ttf").toExternalForm(), 36);
titleLabel.setFont(pikzel);
```