# Resource not found or path invalid JavaFX Image

Tags: java, image, url, javafx

I am working with JavaFX and trying to create an Image object in the main class but it keeps saying invalid URL or resource not found. My image is located in a Icons package which is a subpackage of the main package

```java
Image image = new Image("com/example/fluganzeigetafel/Icons/print.png");
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found 
        at javafx.graphics@19-ea/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1123)
```

See the directory on the image:

[image]

Comment: Your path is correct, but your resource is in the wrong location. In a Maven based project, resources belong under `src/main/resources` (just like with `src/main/java`, subdirectories therein are "packages"). See [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/6395627) for more information.

Comment: Given your project appears to be modular, you may also want to read the "Image Resource" section of one of [my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275656/6395627).

Comment: As an aside, that stack trace indicates you're using version 19-ea of JavaFX. That `ea` bit stands for "early access". Such releases should typically only be used if you need to ensure ahead of time that your application will continue to work in the future. Besides, JavaFX 19 itself is end-of-life anyway. Use JavaFX 17.0.9 (latest LTS release as of this comment) or JavaFX 21.0.1 (latest release as of this comment; also an LTS release). Note JavaFX 20+ requires Java 17+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put this kind of files inside your `resources` folder. Then, you can simply access it using:

```java
InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/Icons/print.png");
Image image = new Image(is);
```

See [How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Answer (score 1):

**Maven operates on convention-based principles. Consequently, within the `/java` folder, only `.java` files are recognized, and all other files are ignored.** Thus, creating files like `README.md` within the `/java` folder will not be included in the build process.

**But All files within the `/resource` folder are included in the build(copied).** If you want to manage resource files within the `/java` folder, modify the `pom.xml` settings as follows:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                <include>**/*.css</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    ...

</build>
```

The configuration above includes all `.fxml` and `.css` extension files within the `/java` folder in the build output. Additionally, it includes all files within the `/resources` folder.

---

**The final build results can be found in the `/target` folder.** To verify if `print.png` included in the build(to check if it was copied correctly), navigate through the `/target` folder.

If it exists but errors still occur, then it might be a path configuration issue. Similarly, you can specify paths based on the output within the `/target`  folder.